# Print Ansible Variables

Tags: variables, printing, ansible

I am attempting to print specific variables while running Ansible playbook.

The information I am looking to print is the 'hostname' and 'software version'. I can print output after using the debug option using "    - debug: var=output" but I received the following error while I try to print specific variables "output.devices.hostname": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

Here is my debug statement: - debug: var=output.devices.hostname. Here is the overall debug output. TIA for any help you can provide.

```
            TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
           ok: [bigIp-a] => {
        "output": {
            "changed": true,
            "devices": [
                {
                    "active_modules": [
                        "DNSSEC",
                        "Remote Desktop",
                        "External Interface and Network HSM, VE",
                        "DNS Rate Fallback, Unlimited",
                        "Firewall Checks",
                        "Max Compression, VE",
                        "Acceleration Manager, VE",
                        "Rate Shaping",
                        "Network Access",
                        "WOM, VE",
                        "DNS Express",
                        "SSL, Forward Proxy, VE",
                        "Base Endpoint Security Checks",
                        "Ram Cache",
                        "DNS Rate Limit, Unlimited QPS",
                        "Machine Certificate Checks",
                        "DNS Services (LAB)",
                        "Secure Virtual Keyboard",
                        "SDN Services, VE",
                        "Anti-Virus Checks",
                        "ASM, VE",
                        "STP",
                        "Advanced Protocols, VE",
                        "PSM, VE",
                        "APM, Web Application",
                        "AFM, VE (LAB ONLY - NO ROUTING)",
                        "App Tunnel",
                        "WBA, VE",
                        "DNS Licensed Objects, Unlimited",
                        "IPV6 Gateway",
                        "SSL, VE",
                        "AAM, Upgrade from WAM, (v11.4 & later)",
                        "Protected Workspace"
                    ],
                    "base_mac_address": "00:0c:29:41:92:07",
                    "build": "1.0.196",
                    "chassis_id": "564d22ff-08a0-b9a5-f4ccb7419207",
                    "chassis_type": "individual",
                    "configsync_address": "10.1.20.242",
                    "edition": "Hotfix HF1",
                    "failover_state": "active",
                    "full_path": "/Common/bigIp-b.min.local.lab",
                    "hostname": "bigIp-b.min.local.lab",
                    "management_address": "10.1.1.246",
                    "marketing_name": "BIG-IP Virtual Edition",
                    "multicast_address": "any",
                    "name": "bigIp-b.min.local.lab",
                    "optional_modules": [
                        "App Mode (TMSH Only, No Root/Bash)",
                        "BIG-IP VE, Multicast Routing",
                        "IPI Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "IPI Subscription, 3Yr, VE",
                        "PEM URL Filtering, Subscription, 1Yr, 200Mbps",
                        "PEM URL Filtering, Subscription, 3Yr, 200Mbps",
                        "PEM, Quota Management, VE",
                        "PEM, VE",
                        "Routing Bundle, VE",
                        "SWG Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "SWG Subscription, 3Yr, VE",
                        "URL Filtering Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "URL Filtering Subscription, 3Yr, VE"
                    ],
                    "platform_id": "Z100",
                    "primary_mirror_address": "10.1.20.242",
                    "product": "BIG-IP",
                    "self": "no",
                    "software_version": "12.1.1",
                    "timezone": "America/Chicago",
                    "unicast_addresses": [
                        {
                            "effective_ip": "10.1.20.242",
                            "effective_port": 1026,
                            "ip": "10.1.20.242",
                            "port": 1026
                        },
                        {
                            "effective_ip": "management-ip",
                            "effective_port": 1026,
                            "ip": "management-ip",
                            "port": 1026
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "active_modules": [
                        "DNSSEC",
                        "Remote Desktop",
                        "External Interface and Network HSM, VE",
                        "DNS Rate Fallback, Unlimited",
                        "Firewall Checks",
                        "Max Compression, VE",
                        "Acceleration Manager, VE",
                        "Rate Shaping",
                        "Network Access",
                        "WOM, VE",
                        "DNS Express",
                        "SSL, Forward Proxy, VE",
                        "Base Endpoint Security Checks",
                        "Ram Cache",
                        "DNS Rate Limit, Unlimited QPS",
                        "Machine Certificate Checks",
                        "DNS Services (LAB)",
                        "Secure Virtual Keyboard",
                        "SDN Services, VE",
                        "Anti-Virus Checks",
                        "ASM, VE",
                        "STP",
                        "Advanced Protocols, VE",
                        "PSM, VE",
                        "APM, Web Application",
                        "AFM, VE (LAB ONLY - NO ROUTING)",
                        "App Tunnel",
                        "WBA, VE",
                        "DNS Licensed Objects, Unlimited",
                        "IPV6 Gateway",
                        "SSL, VE",
                        "AAM, Upgrade from WAM, (v11.4 & later)",
                        "Protected Workspace"
                    ],
                    "base_mac_address": "00:0c:29:31:fc:47",
                    "build": "1.0.196",
                    "chassis_id": "564de91e-b7c1-bda0-1bec5e31fc47",
                    "chassis_type": "individual",
                    "configsync_address": "10.1.20.241",
                    "edition": "Hotfix HF1",
                    "failover_state": "standby",
                    "full_path": "/Common/bigip-a.min.local.lab",
                    "hostname": "bigIp-a.min.local.lab",
                    "management_address": "10.1.1.245",
                    "marketing_name": "BIG-IP Virtual Edition",
                    "multicast_address": "any",
                    "name": "bigip-a.min.local.lab",
                    "optional_modules": [
                        "App Mode (TMSH Only, No Root/Bash)",
                        "BIG-IP VE, Multicast Routing",
                        "IPI Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "IPI Subscription, 3Yr, VE",
                        "PEM URL Filtering, Subscription, 1Yr, 200Mbps",
                        "PEM URL Filtering, Subscription, 3Yr, 200Mbps",
                        "PEM, Quota Management, VE",
                        "PEM, VE",
                        "Routing Bundle, VE",
                        "SWG Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "SWG Subscription, 3Yr, VE",
                        "URL Filtering Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "URL Filtering Subscription, 3Yr, VE"
                    ],
                    "platform_id": "Z100",
                    "primary_mirror_address": "10.1.20.241",
                    "product": "BIG-IP",
                    "self": "yes",
                    "software_version": "12.1.1",
                    "timezone": "America/Chicago",
                    "unicast_addresses": [
                        {
                            "effective_ip": "10.1.20.241",
                            "effective_port": 1026,
                            "ip": "10.1.20.241",
                            "port": 1026
                        },
                        {
                            "effective_ip": "management-ip",
                            "effective_port": 1026,
                            "ip": "management-ip",
                            "port": 1026
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "failed": false
        }
    }
            ok: [bigIp-b] => {
        "output": {
            "changed": true,
            "devices": [
                {
                    "active_modules": [
                        "DNSSEC",
                        "Remote Desktop",
                        "External Interface and Network HSM, VE",
                        "DNS Rate Fallback, Unlimited",
                        "Firewall Checks",
                        "Max Compression, VE",
                        "Acceleration Manager, VE",
                        "Rate Shaping",
                        "Network Access",
                        "WOM, VE",
                        "DNS Express",
                        "SSL, Forward Proxy, VE",
                        "Base Endpoint Security Checks",
                        "Ram Cache",
                        "DNS Rate Limit, Unlimited QPS",
                        "Machine Certificate Checks",
                        "DNS Services (LAB)",
                        "Secure Virtual Keyboard",
                        "SDN Services, VE",
                        "Anti-Virus Checks",
                        "ASM, VE",
                        "STP",
                        "Advanced Protocols, VE",
                        "PSM, VE",
                        "APM, Web Application",
                        "AFM, VE (LAB ONLY - NO ROUTING)",
                        "App Tunnel",
                        "WBA, VE",
                        "DNS Licensed Objects, Unlimited",
                        "IPV6 Gateway",
                        "SSL, VE",
                        "AAM, Upgrade from WAM, (v11.4 & later)",
                        "Protected Workspace"
                    ],
                    "base_mac_address": "00:0c:29:41:92:07",
                    "build": "1.0.196",
                    "chassis_id": "564d22ff-08a0-b9a5-f4ccb7419207",
                    "chassis_type": "individual",
                    "configsync_address": "10.1.20.242",
                    "edition": "Hotfix HF1",
                    "failover_state": "active",
                    "full_path": "/Common/bigIp-b.min.local.lab",
                    "hostname": "bigIp-b.min.local.lab",
                    "management_address": "10.1.1.246",
                    "marketing_name": "BIG-IP Virtual Edition",
                    "multicast_address": "any",
                    "name": "bigIp-b.min.local.lab",
                    "optional_modules": [
                        "App Mode (TMSH Only, No Root/Bash)",
                        "BIG-IP VE, Multicast Routing",
                        "IPI Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "IPI Subscription, 3Yr, VE",
                        "PEM URL Filtering, Subscription, 1Yr, 200Mbps",
                        "PEM URL Filtering, Subscription, 3Yr, 200Mbps",
                        "PEM, Quota Management, VE",
                        "PEM, VE",
                        "Routing Bundle, VE",
                        "SWG Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "SWG Subscription, 3Yr, VE",
                        "URL Filtering Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "URL Filtering Subscription, 3Yr, VE"
                    ],
                    "platform_id": "Z100",
                    "primary_mirror_address": "10.1.20.242",
                    "product": "BIG-IP",
                    "self": "yes",
                    "software_version": "12.1.1",
                    "timezone": "America/Chicago",
                    "unicast_addresses": [
                        {
                            "effective_ip": "10.1.20.242",
                            "effective_port": 1026,
                            "ip": "10.1.20.242",
                            "port": 1026
                        },
                        {
                            "effective_ip": "management-ip",
                            "effective_port": 1026,
                            "ip": "management-ip",
                            "port": 1026
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "active_modules": [
                        "DNSSEC",
                        "Remote Desktop",
                        "External Interface and Network HSM, VE",
                        "DNS Rate Fallback, Unlimited",
                        "Firewall Checks",
                        "Max Compression, VE",
                        "Acceleration Manager, VE",
                        "Rate Shaping",
                        "Network Access",
                        "WOM, VE",
                        "DNS Express",
                        "SSL, Forward Proxy, VE",
                        "Base Endpoint Security Checks",
                        "Ram Cache",
                        "DNS Rate Limit, Unlimited QPS",
                        "Machine Certificate Checks",
                        "DNS Services (LAB)",
                        "Secure Virtual Keyboard",
                        "SDN Services, VE",
                        "Anti-Virus Checks",
                        "ASM, VE",
                        "STP",
                        "Advanced Protocols, VE",
                        "PSM, VE",
                        "APM, Web Application",
                        "AFM, VE (LAB ONLY - NO ROUTING)",
                        "App Tunnel",
                        "WBA, VE",
                        "DNS Licensed Objects, Unlimited",
                        "IPV6 Gateway",
                        "SSL, VE",
                        "AAM, Upgrade from WAM, (v11.4 & later)",
                        "Protected Workspace"
                    ],
                    "base_mac_address": "00:0c:29:31:fc:47",
                    "build": "1.0.196",
                    "chassis_id": "564de91e-b7c1-bda0-1bec5e31fc47",
                    "chassis_type": "individual",
                    "configsync_address": "10.1.20.241",
                    "edition": "Hotfix HF1",
                    "failover_state": "standby",
                    "full_path": "/Common/bigip-a.min.local.lab",
                    "hostname": "BIG-IP-6A.Yellow.Lab",
                    "management_address": "10.1.1.245",
                    "marketing_name": "BIG-IP Virtual Edition",
                    "multicast_address": "any",
                    "name": "bigip-a.min.local.lab",
                    "optional_modules": [
                        "App Mode (TMSH Only, No Root/Bash)",
                        "BIG-IP VE, Multicast Routing",
                        "IPI Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "IPI Subscription, 3Yr, VE",
                        "PEM URL Filtering, Subscription, 1Yr, 200Mbps",
                        "PEM URL Filtering, Subscription, 3Yr, 200Mbps",
                        "PEM, Quota Management, VE",
                        "PEM, VE",
                        "Routing Bundle, VE",
                        "SWG Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "SWG Subscription, 3Yr, VE",
                        "URL Filtering Subscription, 1Yr, VE",
                        "URL Filtering Subscription, 3Yr, VE"
                    ],
                    "platform_id": "Z100",
                    "primary_mirror_address": "10.1.20.241",
                    "product": "BIG-IP",
                    "self": "no",
                    "software_version": "12.1.1",
                    "timezone": "America/Chicago",
                    "unicast_addresses": [
                        {
                            "effective_ip": "10.1.20.241",
                            "effective_port": 1026,
                            "ip": "10.1.20.241",
                            "port": 1026
                        },
                        {
                            "effective_ip": "management-ip",
                            "effective_port": 1026,
                            "ip": "management-ip",
                            "port": 1026
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "failed": false
        }
    }
```

Comment: `devices` is an array.  So you need `output.devices[0].active_modules.hostname`.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I am still seeing the same error message.        ok: [bigIp-a] => {
    "output.devices[0].active_modules.hostname": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

Comment: That's because I goofed.  The `hostname` attribute is not in `active_modules`.  So it should just be `output.devices[0].hostname`.

Comment: No worries, really appreciate your help. Using output.devices[0].hostname, only print hostname for the first device. What if I need to print hostnames for both devices. At some point, I expect to have close to about 140 devices.

Comment: This is what I see after running the playbook.       TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [bigIp-a] => {
    "output.devices[0].hostname": "bigIp-b.min.local.lab"
}
ok: [bigIp-b] => {
    "output.devices[0].hostname": "bigIp-b.min.local.lab"
}

Comment: Yup.  That's what you're supposed to see.  What were you expecting?

Comment: @Jack My debug has a similar output for [device-a] and [device-b]. 
Pasting part of the output.... 
`ok: [bigIp-a] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": true,
        "devices": [
            {
.....
                    "Protected Workspace"
                ],

                "hostname": "bigIp-b.min.local.lab",
.......
ok: [bigIp-b] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": true,
        "devices": [...
                    "Protected Workspace"
                ],
                "hostname": "bigIp-b.min.local.lab",'`

Comment: @Jack. Just posted some additional information. I am running this playbook against two devices. Initial output is only from a single device. I have very similar output form two devices. The aim is to print hostname and down the road a number of variables from other devices as well. Sorry, hope this helps.

Comment: I tried pasting the initial output here in its entirety but couldn't due to space limitations.

Answer (score 0):

From our discussion in the comments, this play should show you what you want:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.hostname }}"
    with_items: "{{ output.devices }}"
```

I got the following:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "bigIp-b.min.local.lab"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "BIG-IP-6A.Yellow.Lab"
}
```

Using the `var` option to `debug`, the task looks like this:

```
  - debug:
      var: item.hostname 
    with_items: "{{ output.devices }}"
```

And gives this as output:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.hostname": "bigIp-b.min.local.lab"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.hostname": "BIG-IP-6A.Yellow.Lab"
}
```